# Elementary question about quiver

Tags: soft-question

How do we add elements in a quiver?

Please see here:

[Link](https://planetmath.org/AdmissibleIdealsBoundQuiverAndItsAlgebra)

I know how to multiply this (by concatenation) but how do we add them,
i.e how do we interpet ab - c ? I don't understand why ab- c is not an element of $R^{2}$.

Comment: You should ask this on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Just formally, think of non-commuting variables in a polynomial ring.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain why ab - c is not an element of $R^{2}$?

Comment: Is it simply because assuming it is true then ab is $R^{2}$ because it has length $2$ and since $R^{2}$ is an ideal then $R^{2}$ contains $ab-(ab-c)=c$ which has length $1$ so impossible?

Comment: Yes, that's right.